Windows: install an *older* driver version from command line
My TP-Link Archer USB Wi-Fi dongle started acting up a couple weeks ago: latency to my AP spikes to 2800+ms every ~10 secs.  This is a common problem it seems, but none of the suggestions on the web worked; however, I discovered that if I install another driver the spikes get reduced to an unnoticeable ~20ms.  Usually the Archer T4U Plus(EU) v2.0_win10win11_08022021,1030.44.0531.2021 for Win10 do the trick (even tho I've an US dongle, not EU, I'm on Win11, not 10, and I downloaded the v2.6, but they give the v2.0 file), but every now and then it doesn't and I've to install others until it's happy.
The thing is, Windows "helpfully" reinstalls the latest Microsoft signed driver everytime I turn the laptop back on.  I tried deleting it to force the old driver, but then that one spikes, so, whatever the problem with the dongle is, it wants a driver change to be usable.
So, I'd like a way to force the install of the old driver programmatically, so I don't have to do it by hand every time it starts lagging.  Following the suggestions at this post, I found that doing pnputil -i -a netrtwlanu.inf imports the driver, but doesn't install it since it only does so with the highest priority one, according to the docs.
And the old way, rundll32.exe advpack.dll,LaunchINFSectionEx netrtwlanu.inf,RTL8812au.ndi.NT,,4,N, keeps asking for rtwlanu.sys again and again, even after I select it in the file dialog.
Any way to force installing a specific driver from a script?

I don't think you'll need to script anything to solve this issue. Automatic driver updates can be disabled by going to:

Control Panel > Devices and Printers > [Right-click your machine] > Device Installation Settings

Here you can disable the automatic driver update by selecting the "No..." radio button and saving.
Attaching screenshots for reference.

Devices and Printers Screen
Disable driver updates


Thanks, tried your suggestion, but after a week, Windows still reverts to the latest driver on every boot/wake.  And as mentioned, I must reinstall a driver for the spikes to be manageable, sometimes multiple times;  deleting the Windows driver to force the old one still produced spikes.  Don't ask me why, Murphy went specially postal in this one.  If I could install specific driver versions from a script, at least I could do it quickly, or even automate it on high latency.  I bought the dongle like 8 months ago, so I don't wanna trash it so soon.

@Chema This is a mess. Expected with Windows tbh. Time to contact TP-Link support and check their forums if anyone else has had this issue.
